# Performing arithmetic/comparisons on values of different keys during a for loop iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary with hundreds of keys. How can I run a for loop and perform comparisons/arithmetic operations on different keys/value pairs?

Here's a small example of the dictionary:

```
dict = {
        "001": {
            "d": "7179.6201",
            "f": "7183.6201",
        },
        "002": {
            "d": "7112.0200",
            "f": "7166.0000",
        },
        "003": {
            "d": "7255.0000",
            "f": "7128.5400",
        },
        "004": (
            "d": "7250.0000",
            "f": "7128.2000"
        }
    }
```

The for loop should cycle through every key/value pair and perform two operations. (1) If the "d" value for "001" (or any key) is greater than the "d" value for "002" (or any key+1), then return the key ("001", for this particular iteration) and its corresponding "d" value. (2) If that "d" value is greater than the following "d" value, then subtract both numbers (convert from string to number) and return the difference.

Desired result for running the code on this particular dictionary:

```
"001": "7179.6201", diff: "67.6001"
"003": "7255.0000", diff: "5.0000"
```

I understand how to call out those key/value pairs, but I don't even know how to begin comparing values of different keys especially when I cannot explicitly reference the key itself. I'd like to provide code for what I've done, but I don't even know where to start for something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Will the keys be of this 3 digit sequence all the way?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RamkishoreM - unfortunately, no.  I tried what you mentioned about using a "key + 1", but the keys are not sequential.  They also skip; for example "001", then "003", then "006", etc.  In all of the for loops I've tried, I can reference the "d" value, but I am stuck with referencing the "d" value of the next loop iteration.  

for k,v in dict.items():
 print(v["d"])
 print(k+1[v]["d"])     <-- not really sure how to reference the next iteration "d" value.  Surprisingly, I haven't found any examples that show this.  They start talking about using pandas but that is way beyond my level.

Comment: Will they still be in numerically sorted order?

Comment: @RamkishoreM - that brings me to my next problem!  It is my understanding that dictionary keys aren't ordered.  In my situation, I am converting JSON to a dictionary.  For some reason, the keys are showing up in order (either the keys are dates or some numbers).  When I perform my arithmetic, I am hoping that they will always stay in that order (ascending dates, for example).  If the JSON is converted to dictionary and the keys are 'out of order', then I'll have to find a way to put them back into order.  I figured that I would work on one problem at a time :)

Comment: `data.keys()` will contain a list of keys. You can loop over `range(len(data.keys()))` to get current and next keys

Comment: @RamkishoreM - ahh, so this is a reason I should show all of my work.  I did do exactly what you are suggesting but let's say you are in iteration "3".  How do you reference a value of iteration "4" while you are in iteration "3", especially, when you have no way of explicitly referencing a key?

Comment: when looping over range you can get both keys `data.keys()[i], data.keys()[i+1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict1 = {"001": {"d": "7179.6201", "f": "7183.6201"}, "002": {"d": "7112.0200", "f": "7166.0000"},
     "003": {"d": "7255.0000", "f": "7128.5400"}, "004": {"d": "7250.0000","f": "7128.2000"}}

dict1 = OrderedDict(dict1) 
for index in range(len(dict1) - 1):
    if float(list(dict1.items())[index][1]['d']) > float(list(dict1.items())[index + 1][1]['d']):
        print(list(dict1.items())[index][0] + ':' + list(dict1.items())[index][1]['d'] + "    diff:" + \
          str(float(list(dict1.items())[index][1]['d']) - float(list(dict1.items())[index+1][1]['d'])))
    else:
        pass
```

Explanation:

First make sure dictionary have an sequence order using collections.OrderedDict()

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dict1 = OrderedDict(dict1)
```

Using for loop iterate until last element:

```
for index in range(len(dict1) - 1):
```

compare the "d" value of current index and next index using if statement:

```
if float(list(dict1.items())[index][1]['d']) > float(list(dict1.items())[index + 1][1]['d']):
```

If it is true, print the format which you required and also adding the difference too.

```
print(list(dict1.items())[index][0] + ':' + list(dict1.items())[index][1]['d'] + "    diff:" + \
      str(float(list(dict1.items())[index][1]['d']) - float(list(dict1.items())[index+1][1]['d'])))
```

Note: This is tested in my machine with python == 3.6 and got the output which is your desired output!!

Comment: @Aaron If you need any explanation you can ask me. I will update my explanation

Comment: Thanks for that!  It was the list conversion that I was missing and the reason I kept getting indexing issues.  Next time, I will be sure to post my work; perhaps that will save you all some time in assisting me :)

Answer (score 1):

If your keys follow that sequence, you can get next key from current key

```
for key in data:
    next_key = "{:03d}".format(int(key) + 1)
    try:
        current_d, next_d = data[key]['d'], data[next_key]['d']
    except KeyError:
        print('End of data')
    else:
        d_diff = float(current_d) - float(next_d)
        if d_diff > 0:
            print('{}: {}, diff: {}'.format(key, current_d, d_diff))
```

Comment: In the future, please don't respond to lazy questions like this one, where OP does not demonstrate any real effort. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Wow, I am bound to find bullies where ever I go.  I felt that the question was decently written and clear - not lazily written.  However, the perceived effort in solving the problem could be considered 'lazy'.  Regardless, being that you are a relatively high profile user on SO, I'd think you'd want to create a friendlier atmosphere.  Instead of just downgrading the question and insulting me, it would be nice if you were a bit more welcoming and politely informed me of the proper SO customs.  I'd be more than happy to engage and share what I've tried (but not with you).